# Microsoft Jscript Email Module?

Tags: email, javascript

I was wondering if there is an Email module for MS Jscript (not Jscript .net) similar to the one in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Collaboration Data Objects (CDO)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171440) COM API.

Here's how you can send a text e-mail using CDO:

```
SendEMail("from@example.com", "to@example.com", "Subject", "Text body"); 

function SendEMail(from, to, subject, body)
{
  try
  {
    var oMsg      = new ActiveXObject("CDO.Message");
    oMsg.From     = from;
    oMsg.To       = to;
    oMsg.Subject  = subject;
    oMsg.TextBody = body;
    oMsg.Send(); 
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    WScript.Echo("Error: " + e.description);
  }
}
```

[This page](http://www.paulsadowski.com/WSH/cdo.htm) provides some more CDO usage examples (they're in VBScript, but should help you get the idea). See also the [CDO Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526694(EXCHG.10).aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: Cheers, I've had a look and managed to send an email via gmail :)