# Compare Folder Date/Time with System Date/Time. If no change in '4' hours then send alert

Tags: batch-file

Currently looking for a batch script that would allow me to compare a folder with the system time for inactivity.

For example, if a folder's modified date hasn't been updated in 4> hours than it will either send an email or generate a log file.

I'm a novice when it comes to writing up batch files or Powershel scripts.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Googling for `batch script to compare a folder time with the system time` gives (regardless your question is first-placed) next (IMHO good) [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6845498/3439404] starting point for you... Feel free to [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28213625/edit) to share growths  achieved so far or if you could hang on anything

Comment: I recommend [borrowing from a WSH runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27297874/1683264) (VBScript or JScript) for this.  Bonus: That hybrid script I linked can be combined Captain Planet style with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1129822/1683264) to add the email functionality you want.